# Displaying values in a spreadsheet up to X days away from current date

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc

I'm looking to get some assistance in untangling the mess that is a data entry and summary spreadsheet I've had for the last few years in LibreOffice Calc. The general layout of the spreadsheet's relevant parts are as follows:

Sheet: "Data Entry"

```
|A    |B    |...  |L    |
|-----|-----|-----|-----|
|Date |Name |...  |Value|
```

Sheet: "Summary"

```
|A    |...  |E           |G                       |
|-----|-----|------------|------------------------|
|Name |...  |Total Values|Values from last 90 days|
```

At the moment, everything works, but I wish to add a new function to the Summary sheet, which is column G. Column E runs a complex formula to search the Data Entry sheet for every row where cells in Summary column A match cells in Data Entry column B. Here is that formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Data Entry'.$B$3:INDIRECT("'Data Entry'.B"&'Data Entry'.$A$1+2)=A1)*ISNUMBER('Data Entry'.$L$3:INDIRECT("'Data Entry'.L"&'Data Entry'.$A$1+2)),('Data Entry'.$L$3:INDIRECT("'Data Entry'.L"&'Data Entry'.$A$1+2)))
```

This is an absolutely confusing mess, I know. I'll attempt to simplify the formula below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B100=A1)*ISNUMBER(L1:L100),(L1:L100))
```

What I was wondering is how I could modify this formula for Summary column G, where its search would only be limited to the last 90 days.

An example of what I should see:

Sheet: "Data Entry"

```
|A       |B    |...|L|
|--------|-----|---|-|
|19-08-13|Name1|...|2|
|19-07-25|Name2|...|1|
|19-01-01|Name1|...|3|
```

Sheet: "Summary"

```
|A    |...|E|G|
|-----|---|-|-|
|Name1|...|5|2|
|Name2|...|1|1|
```

EDIT: The following gives me a 502 error:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(('Data Entry'.$B$3:INDIRECT("'Data Entry'.B"&'Data Entry'.$A$1+2)=A6)*ISNUMBER('Data Entry'.$L$3:INDIRECT("'Data Entry'.L"&'Data Entry'.$A$1+2))*('Data Entry'.A3:"'Data Entry'.A"&'Data Entry'.$A$1+2>TODAY()-91),('Data Entry'.$L$3:INDIRECT("'Data Entry'.L"&'Data Entry'.$A$1+2))*('Data Entry'.A3:"'Data Entry'.A"&'Data Entry'.$A$1+2>TODAY()-91))
```

Comment: Can your data ever contain a future date?  Also, col B appears to be text, so it isn't clear what's going on in your SUMPRODUCT.  And what's in A1?

Comment: Without trying to unravel your formulas, if col A contains the dates, include a condition `(A1:A100>TODAY()-91).  That assumes there can't be future dates in the data.  BTW, if you will be copying the formula to populate other cells, you probably want absolute addressing in the range references.

Comment: Summary.A1 is the string to be searched in DataEntry.B1:100. For every row where the strings match, the values in DataEntry.L1:100 are added up. And no, all dates are in the past. As for the condition you posted, could you explain how it works, and how I'd integrate it with the formula in my question?

Comment: You'd basically do it the same way as your name condition.  It looks like col L contains the values you're summing?  If so, multiply that by this condition, like `(L1:L100)*(A1:A100>TODAY()-91)`.  The date test will evaluate to 1 for qualifying dates, or 0 for non-qualifying, so only values associated with qualifying dates will return a value.  Actually, you could just make it another argument in the SUMTOTAL: `...(L1:L100),(A1:A100>TODAY()-91)`

Comment: Edited my question with one of the formulas I tried using that condition. Getting a 502 error.

Comment: This is going to be hard for people to figure out without knowing what's in the referenced cells.  A couple of things to double-check: make sure you don't have circular references.  It looks like your data starts in row 3 and you have a reference to A6.  It isn't clear what's going on with the $A$1+2 that becomes part of a cell reference in INDIRECT (what's in A1?).  I would try testing SUMPRODUCT with each argument separately to see what it's doing.

Comment: BTW, LO Calc can be set to use Excel-style addressing (which includes, among other things, sheetname!range rather than sheetname.range.  That will make it easier to get support on SU (unless you have always used LO and that would confuse you at this point, or it would mess up support for a lot of legacy spreadsheets).  The site has a lot of Excel pros but far fewer LO pros, and the native LO addressing confuses the hell out of Excel pros who aren't familiar with it.  :-)

Comment: A1 contains a formula that sums up how many entries there are. This allows every other formula I have to only go through the exact number of entries I have, so I don't assign an arbitrary range like 1:5000, which would slow down the processing considerably. As for LO vs Excel, I've always used OO/LO, so Excel would likely be confusing by this point for me.

Comment: Figured it out. If you want to post the test condition as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it.

Comment: Kudos for figuring it out, and it's always satisfying to have a part in solving a problem.  :-)  I tried to include some explanation in the answer for novice Excel users who might have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question describes two issues.  One is trying to debug a long formula.  Generally, the key to that is to break the formula down to its component pieces and test each piece to see what it's doing.  Start by keeping logical chunks intact (i.e., several expressions that work together), to identify which section of the formula isn't working.  If the error isn't obvious from that, break the section into its component parts.

Do that by copying and pasting each part, and then adjust the pasted piece to make it a standalone formula (like add the equal sign).  In case the problem is unbalanced parentheses, copy the entire expression that contains all of the parentheses, then delete other internal expressions and their parentheses, which will be easier to spot; unbalanced parentheses in what's left may become obvious just from this exercise. Copying and pasting will ensure that the problem will be included in what you test; retyping the formula can fix mistakes, and everything works when you test so it doesn't serve a diagnostic purpose.

The other issue was limiting the results to the last 90 days.  This can be done similar to how the formula already limits results to the matching name -- add a test to the list of expressions in SUMPRODUCT.  To keep things simple, I'll leave out the complexity of using INDIRECT to build the ranges and just show fixed ranges.  In context, the additional argument could look like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT( ... (L1:L100), (A1:A100>TODAY()-91) ... )
```

The (L1:L100) is just to show location in the simplified example in the question.

Dates are stored as day counts, so values are in units of days.  You can directly add or subtract days.  The expression `>TODAY()-91` tests for dates older than today by no more than 90 days.  This assumes your data cannot contain future dates, since those would be included if you don't expand the formula to limit that, also.  The whole expression is a logical test that returns either TRUE (`1`) or FALSE (`0`).  SUMPRODUCT multiplies the rest of the array result by those values, resulting in either a zero or whatever is the result of the other arguments in the SUMPRODUCT.